# assinging `grep "string"|wc -l` into a variable in batch scripting

Tags: if-statement, grep, batch-file, wc

I am trying to develop a batch equivalent (windows) code of below unix script:-

```
i=`grep "ora-error" *.txt|wc -l`
if [ i -gt 0 ]; then
echo "true"
else
echo "false"
fi
```

tried with "find /c "ora-error" *.txt" but was not able to take the o/p in to variable and redirect the same to if condition...

ie. when I use "find /c "ora-error" *.txt" below is the output

---------- xx.TXT: 0

---------- yy.TXT: 0

---------- zz.TXT: 0

I want to take the count and redirect valur into a IF condition.

I need a window script to solve this issue.

Can any body help on this...

Thanks in advance..

with regards

sree

Guys worked out a solution....

```
find /c "ora-error" *.txt>TEST1.txt
find /c "0" TEST1.TXT>TEST2.TXT
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=:" %%A IN (TEST2.TXT) DO SET a=%%B
set _count=%a%
IF %_count% EQU 4 goto matched
IF not %_count% EQU 4 goto notmatched

:matched
echo we are in equal to 4 loop
pause
exit

:notmatched
echo we are in not equal to 4 loop
pause
exit
```

Comment: Why don't you post your solution as an answer? Stack overflow users are encouraged to do this and you can even mark you answer as the accepted answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "ora-error" *.txt>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "true"
else
echo "false"
fi
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying trying to develop code in windows not in unix -